# How can I make ADB behave like real deeplink?

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I can verify my deeplink if it is properly verified. I can use

```
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur <package name>
```

Which provides various data. But to be fully ascertained, I want to try deeplink and see it works (go directly into the app without asking).

However, I notice when I use adb as below,

```
adb shell am start -d https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/48033927
```

It will always prompt which App to use (eg shown below), both for deeplink url that is successful verified or not

[image]

I can't find any way to deeplink using `adb` to behave like actual deeplink from a URL clicked.

I mean I want to find an `adb` command when triggered (that behave like normal deeplink)

- it will deeplink without need to ask for which app to open if the url has been verified, or
- reject and go to browser if it is not verified, even if it is in the manifest.

Is there any parameter I can give to `adb` to emulate the actual deeplink behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'll have to add `-a android.intent.action.VIEW`

e.g.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/48033927
```