# What's the use of "-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" for "adb shell am start"?

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking, android-deep-link, browsable

What's the different between

```
adb shell am start \
   -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
   -d https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/48033927
```

and

```
adb shell am start \
   -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
   -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
   -d https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/48033927
```

Note: I know the use of `-a android.intent.action.VIEW` and without as per this [How can I make ADB behave like real deeplink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528436/how-can-i-make-adb-behave-like-real-deeplink), but can't find what's the different between using `-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` and not

Answer (score 1):

This is a `category` which the intent can have many and specified as

```
[-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
```

see also https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element

#### edit

If `BROWSABLE` the target activity allows itself to be started by a web browser to display data referenced by a link, such as an image or an e-mail message.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: Thanks. But what difference does it make if one has BROWSABLE vs not having it through the ADB way of deeplink?

Answer (score 1):

It might not make any difference, because `-a` is the action and `-c` is the category. When passing action `VIEW` and an URL, it is save to assume that this shall be `BROWSABLE`. Ultimately it all depends what the `intent-filter` in `AndroidManifest.xml` has declared. When passing a category like `BROWSABLE`, one still can choose alternate apps, while available - else it should be the default.

Comment: Thanks Martin. That's what I thought, there's no point supplying the "-c". But curious why Google in their example in https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#auto-verification, shows using "-c".

Comment: @Elye I think it should become more obvious, when leaving the action or even URL away... the `PackageManager` scans all `AndroidManifest.xml` intents... and the category indicates which to show in the corresponding selector GUI then. Eg. a web-browser would have a very unspecific URL filter, while otherwise it's filtered by the domain name.